# I want to disable a widget if there is no data in the futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a pageview with widget1 and widget2 both use a futurebuilder i want to disable widget2 and swipe if there is no data in his futurebuilder
I have two pages 1 and 2. I want to stay only on page 1 and also no swipe if in page2 there is no data in the futurebuilder –
the problem is if there is no data in widget1 the pageview becomes empty

```
 controller: controller,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      
                      child: PageView(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

                      children: [
                        Widget1(),
                        Widget2()
                      ]),
                    ),
                    Widget3(),

                   
                    Widget4(),

                   
                    widget5(),
                    widget6(),

                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: FutureBuilder is the top level widget of your PageView?

Comment: the futurebuilder is inside widget 1 and widget 2 each has its own futurebuilder I want to disable widget1 in the pageview if there is no data. to stay only on widget1. the problem is if there is no data in widget1 the pageview becomes empty

Comment: If there is no data on widget 1, you like to stop swap functionality ?

Comment: yes If there is no data on widget 1, i want to show widget2 only and no swipe.
.the problem is if there is no data in widget1 the pageview is empty the widget2 is not displayed

Comment: It's hard to tell what widget has the children: parameter that is holding Widget2().

Comment: It would be easier if you use FutureBuilder on top level widget, top of PageView

Comment: there is no futurebuilder at the top I don't want to impact the other widgets as well

Answer (score 0):

use the visibility widget and add a condition to show your widget.

```
 Visibility(visible: <YOUR CONDITION>, child: Container()),
```

Comment: can you  give me exemple with my code on top

Comment: I think your code is incomplete but let's suppose you have a future builder and you are getting a snapshot you can set your code like:   if(snapshot.hasdata){return Widget2(); }else{return Container();}

Comment: widget1 and widget2 have her own futurebuilder